# css woes, input[type="text"] not overriding *

Tags: css, input

at the top of my css file i say:

```
* {
border:none;
margin:0; 
padding:0;
}
```

but i want to have text input boxes to have a border so a few lines down i say:

```
input[type="text"] {
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color: black;
}
```

No luck! Am I missing something about how CSS works? Doesn't the input declarations override the *?

Comment: How does the corresponding document look like? Did you specify the `type="text"` attribute for that `input` element?

Comment: @Gumbo: wish your comment could be awarded the selected answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a `border-style` as well.  By default, it is `none`.  You probably want `solid`:

```
input[type="text"] {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Or shorthand:

```
input[type="text"] {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Your border: black; is overriding the other border definitions.  Change border: to border-color.

Comment: border-color does the same thing :(

Answer (score 1):

I think input[type="text"] is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: That is true.  IIRC It's a CSS3 selector.

Comment: @strager: The attribute selector was introduced in CSS 2. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

Answer (score 0):

If it is IE6 you cannot do attribute selectors.

http://dev.l-c-n.com/CSS3-selectors/browser-support.php

Answer (score 0):

The input="text" was not specified for my input elements

D'OH!

Answer (score 0):

What if you give the input-tag a class, and refers that class in the CSS.
And why do you have *{border: none;}? Is it because you don't wan't the borders to be shown around the images? Because then you could use the img{botder: none;} instead, and not have the problem...